# Make a transition text without href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I have a div containing a group of divs.

I want the divs inside to work as links that move to another page after saving this link's value.

The div consists of the `id` in the div attribute, & the name in the div's value as follows:

**Html:**

```
    <div id="ClasssesList" ></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
function GetClassesList(data) {
   var classes = (typeof data) == 'string' ? eval('(' + data + ')') : data;
   $('#ClasssesList').empty();
   for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
      var text = '<button class="BigDiv" value="' + classes[i].Cls_ID + '" >' + classes[i].Cls_Name + '</button>';
    $('#ClasssesList').append(text);
   }
}
```

I want to save the value of the clicked `id` in a `localStorage` then move to the next page:

I tried to make it as follows, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
$("#ClasssesList").bind('click', 'button.BigDiv',CallLink()); 

function CallLink(e) {

        localStorage['ClassID'] = $('Button.BigDiv').attr('value');
        window.location.replace("Teacher_Attendance.htm");
 }
```

Do you know what should I do  to let it work ?

Comment: Explain in more detail what the problem is. Is the local storage not saving your values, or problems with the navigation, or just the whole doesn't work?

Comment: No, the local storage saves the value, but the IDE outputs an error "object not supported" when it comes to CallLink()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function CallLink(e) {

        localStorage.setItem('ClassID', $('Button.BigDiv').attr('value'));

        window.location.replace("Teacher_Attendance.htm");
 }
```

And to get that item try:

```
localStorage.getItem('classID');
```

Format to set data to localStorage is

```
localStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

here `value` is `string` format;

you will get more here [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197050%28VS.85%29.aspx), [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage) and [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Name-ValueStorage/Name-ValueStorage.html).

#### And one note

I think your bind function

```
$("#ClasssesList").bind('click', 'button.BigDiv',CallLink())
```

should be written as

```
$("#ClasssesList").on('click', 'button.BigDiv',CallLink())
```

Comment: But when the debugger comes to this line: $("#ClasssesList").bind('click', 'button.BigDiv',CallLink()); 
 it crashes